# Symfony2 Remove empty field in FormType

Tags: php, symfony

I have a onPreSubmit in my Symfony2 FormType.

```
public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();

    // Avoid sending empty RegisterProduct
    foreach ($data['registerProducts'] as $key => $registerProduct) {

        if (empty($registerProduct['quantity'])) {
            unset($data['registerProducts'][ $key ]);
        }
    }

    $event->setData($data);
}
```

The purpose is to remove an array value if a certain fiels in this one is empty (which works)

But when I set the data I have this error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO register_product ..... 
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'register_id' cannot be null
```

I don't understand why.

**EDIT: I tried with onPostSubmit, but still have the same error**

```
public function onPostSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    /** @var Register $register */
    $register = $event->getForm()->getData();

    foreach ($register->getRegisterProducts() as $registerProduct) {

        if ($registerProduct->getQuantity() < 1) {
            $register->removeRegisterProduct($registerProduct);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be done on the PostSubmit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As say in comments, you should do it in `postSubmit` instead of `preSubmit`.

Example :

```
public function onPostSubmit(FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();

    foreach ($data['registerProducts'] as $key => $registerProduct) {

        if (empty($registerProduct['quantity'])) {
            unset($data['registerProducts'][$key]);
        }
    }
});
```

If the SQL error persists, try to replace `$event->getData()` by `$event->getForm()->getData()` , the first returns data from the client.

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, the FormEvent doesn't work.

Also, I'll propose to use the prePersist and preUpdate hooks in your Entity.
It may not be an alternative for you if your question is only about the form context.

Usage :

```
/**
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class YourEntity
{
    // ...

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function manageProducts()
    {
        foreach ($this->getRegisterProducts() as $registerProduct) {
            if ($registerProduct->getQuantity() < 1) {
                $this->removeRegisterProduct($registerProduct);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See the [Events](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html) part of doctrine documentation.

I hope you can use this solution and that it works.

Comment: I tried to do it like you said but still have the same error. I edited my post.

Comment: Did you tried with `$event->getData()` and `unset` ?

Comment: Yes I used `$event->getData()`. With `onPostSubmit $event` does not send me an array anymore but an object. So no `unset`. That's why I used `removeRegisterProduct`. @chalasr

Comment: Can you try the same code as your last edit, but just replace `$event->getForm->getData()` by `$event->getData` ? Thank's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103059/discussion-between-kevinr-and-chalasr).